# How to start Whatsapp Web on Ubuntu with Whatsapp installed on bluestacks on another computer?

Tags: android, android-emulator, whatsapp

I have recently installed bluestacks on a Windows 7 computer which isn't my normal one and I can't use it often and it's kind of annoying because I don't really own it.

I installed Whatsapp on that computer.

Since my normal computer runs Ubuntu I want to run Whatsapp or at least Whatsapp Web on this one.

I tried to scan an image with Whatsapp just on the Windows computers screen just to test whether this could work - the screen stays black.

Can I run Whatsapp on my own computer? If so, how do I make this happen?